# How can I change this deprecated code ? (flutter_inappwebview)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I have my code that uses inappview dependencie but throws this warning:
**Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]**

How can I convert this deprecated code to the new version of code?

```
    public func hide() {
    isHidden = true
    
    // Run later to avoid the "took a long time" log message.
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
            self.tmpWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: 0.0)
            UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.makeKeyAndVisible()
            if self.previousStatusBarStyle != -1 {
                UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle(rawValue: self.previousStatusBarStyle)!
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Overriding `preferredStatusBarStyle` method in you viewController, and call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` method to update status bar's appearance. You could also make you `previousStatusBarStyle` property optional so you can use if-let to check its availability. Overriding `prefersStatusBarHidden` method to return true if you want hide you status bar.

```swift
class YourViewController : UIViewController {
    var previousStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle?

    public func hide() {
        isHidden = true

        // Run later to avoid the "took a long time" log message.
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
            self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
                self.tmpWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: 0.0)
                UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.makeKeyAndVisible()
                if let statusBarStyle = self.previousStatusBarStyle {
                    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
                }
            })
        })
    }
    

    // In your view controller's scope
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return previousStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    }

}
```